Calculating the derivative of the principal part a singular and non-singular function
This might be a naive question, but I am running into a hurdle involving my research which I can't seem to get past. I'm a physics student, by the way. So, my question involves calculating the derivative of the principal part of a simple pole. Assume we have a complex function $f(z)$ where $z$ is a complex variable such that
\begin{equation}
f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{z-z_0} + h(z)
\end{equation}
where $g(z)$ and $h(z)$ are non-singular functions. I could do something very stupid and write
\begin{equation}
f(z) = \frac{g(z) + (z-z_0) h(z)}{z-z_0}
\end{equation}
which should be valid when $z \neq z_0$. The residue of $f(z)$ at $z=z_0$ is equal to $g(z_0)$ which is pretty clear. However, let's say I want to calculate the derivative of the principal part evaluated at $z=z_0$. What I mean is that what I want to evaluate is
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dz} \left[(z-z_0) f(z)\right] \Big\vert_{z=z_0} = g'(z_0) + h(z_0)
\end{equation}
which I think is okay, but I'm not sure if this is completely valid due to some technicality as $h(z)$ was originally non-singular and was well-behaved at $z=z_0$. Note that I am taking the derivative first and then taking the limit.
Please let me know if I am not going crazy or if I am missing something. Thank you :)

this sounds right - not sure why do you have doubts

The principal part at a simple pole is of the form $\frac{a}{z-z_0}$, with a constant in the numerator.
